# Is it possible to undo an edit?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I have just made an edit to [someone's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12969739/351785) by placing the reference link into the surround text. As soon as I submitted the edit, I thought "This isn't actually improving the answer a whole lot" and decided that I wanted to undo or remove my edit suggestion. And then got stuck because I could not locate a way to do this.

Is it possible to undo or remove an edit suggestion?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

As long as the edit was applied immediately (i.e. you have >= 2000 reputation on that site), you can click the [edited 9 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/12969739/revisions) link under the post. You then see the revision history, where you can roll back to the previous version.

If your edits are reviewed (i.e. you have < 2000 reputation on that site), you [cannot retract the edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80933/how-can-i-cancel-an-edit-i-made-on-another-users-question-or-answer).

Comment: Which in effect creates another edit that doesn't change awholeheckofalot :)  Not that useful.

Comment: Yeah if you want to _delete_ a revision, you'll have to flag the post to let a moderator do so, and you'll have to make a pretty good case for it to get it approved (this case: fat chance). OP asked for "undo".

Comment: @CodeCaster looks like edit priviledge is checked separately for every site. My erroneous edit is on askubunutu http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/656334, where I've got only 1216 rep.